# API_URL = "" not recognized when trying to put in the environment variables

Tags: solidity

I am working to put the environment variables into the terminal, after setting .env file. The API_URL = "insert my alchemy code" The variables will be for the alchemy key and the metamask key for NFT project. The language is solidity. Also the PRIVATE_KEY = "Metamask key here", PRIVATE_KEY AND API_URL are not recognized

Answer (score 0):

wherever u want to get environment variables you have to use

```
process.env.API_URL
```

or

```
process.env.PRIVATE_KEY
```

hope it may work.